# Can't get wordpress to stop making an additional HTML section?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, shortcode

hope everyone is having a wonderful afternoon!

I have been developing a website, and have for the most part left with removing unused assets, and cleaning up the code.

I have managed to remove most of the non-essential material, however I can't get past understanding how and why does my HTML produces another separating  , and I cannot find a way of removing it.

The website is managed by Wordpress and is constructed with shortcodes:

**Question:** How do I remove the  up top of the one and only that is needed?

Thank you so much for clarification in advance!

[image: Here is the Shortcode I used:]

[image: This is the additional row that is being created above the real one]
[image: This is the one that is the intended result:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are working with wordpress, and have noticed something similar to my situation, then a problem resides in the WP Dashboard, which in turn is also critical to check if you have all semicolons in place. If not, the loop will continue to repeat itself and hence creating empty rows after rows until it's empty.

In my instance, it was looping trough and checking for contents of rows and hence made an another instance of a row.

Hope this helps to anyone who may encounter similar issues when working with wordpress shortcodes!